# Shift+F1 does not open offline documentation in XML Design Tab in Android Studio but works elsewhere

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I have Android Studio 3.2.1
I have downloaded "Documentation for Android SDK", "Sources for Android 28", "Sources for Android 21", etc from SDK Manager from within Android Studio.
Pressing **Shift+F1** on any View, say, CheckBox, in activity_main.xml (***in Text Mode***) takes me to **offline** documentation repository in a new Browser Tab.
But When I press Shift+F1, on any view present under *Palette* in activity_main.xml (***in Design Tab/Mode***), I am taken to the **online** documentation of the very same thing already present in my offline repository.
So, the question is how to make it use the offline repository *at all the places*, so I can look in the documentation even when I am offline? 
NB:

- This occurs irrespective of me being connected/not-connected to internet.
- Offline Documentation is used everywhere else including Kotlin files. (and without any delay if I am online)
- jdk.table.xml is set up properly and pointing to local reposiories only.

Comment: You could report an issue on Android Studio tracker: https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs#filing-a-bug

Comment: @y.bedrov Is this a bug/problem on your device too? Or just on my device?